# Help in understanding how we arrive at 'reduced form equations'

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

[image: Example]

Referring to equations 1 and 2 above, I understand that the object is to estimate the endogenous variables (consumption (c) and income(y)) as a function of the exogenous or predetermined variables. However, in substituting equation 2 for y in equation 1, why do we then divide each term by 1-Beta (which I understand to be 'power')? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

They skipped some steps between the second and third lines of equation (1). Up to the second line, you have $c_t$ on both sides of the equation. To write down the reduced form, you have to do some algebra to get $c_t$ by itself:
\begin{align}
c_t&=\alpha+\beta y_t+u_t\\
c_t&=\alpha+\beta (c_t+i_t)+u_t\\
c_t&=\alpha+\beta c_t +\beta i_t+u_t\\
c_t-\beta c_t&=\alpha +\beta i_t+u_t\\
(1-\beta)c_t&=\alpha +\beta i_t+u_t\\
c_t&=\frac{1}{1-\beta}(\alpha +\beta i_t+u_t)\\
&=\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta}+\frac{1}{1-\beta}i_t+\frac{1}{1-\beta}u_t.
\end{align}

Comment: Pls. accept the answer and upvote if you find it helpful.